# Does vector erase method needs class to have = operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm doing a computer science project where I use stl library vector as vector (Table is a class implemented by me). When I tried to use erase method without having implemented operator= in my class Table it fails. Then I added = and now it works but I'm not sure that was the problem. Is necessary to have operator= in a class to use erase method?
This is a sample code:

```
vector<Table> tables;
Table t("1");
Table t2("2");

tables.push_back(t);
tables.push_back(t2);

tables.erase(tables.begin());//If no operator = is defined this gives problems
```

Comment: Removing an element from the front or middle of a vector shifts the remaining elements in memory, so they must be [`MoveAssignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable), which requires a copy-assignment or move-assignment operator that can bind to rvalues.

Comment: @cigien I updated my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is necessary to have operator= in a class to use erase method?

Yes, it is required by the standard.

> And why it runs without having it defined?

A class has an implicit assignment operator generated by the compiler by default, except in certain cases (for example, if it has sub objects that are not assignable).

Comment: And why it runs without having it defined?

Comment: If your class is *simple*, the compiler provides it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens in your code. You have two `Table`s in the vector, and then you erase the first one. When you're done, you have one `Table` and it's in the memory location that the first one "used to be"

To do that, the vector needs to copy/move the second one into the spot where the first one is. It does this via assignment.